# how to stop quartz warn loggers

Tags: java, logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler

Console is getting filled with Quartz WARN loggers all the time and it's really annoying to developers who work in the project to find other logger messages in console.

```
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,142]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'system-id'
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,142]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'end-at'
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,143]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'cron-expression'
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,144]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'start-at'
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,144]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'scheduled-job-id'
[2013-09-14 11:18:35,144]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'size'
[2013-09-14 11:18:40,086]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'GNS'
[2013-09-14 11:18:40,087]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'limit'
[2013-09-14 11:18:40,087]  WARN {org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory} -  No setter on Job class lk.gov.elg.admin.action.detain.DetainJob for property 'tenantId'
```

I Google and find a way to do but it didn't give the solution.

```
<logger name="org.quartz">
        <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

We are using log4j.xml instead of log4j.properties.

Here is the snapshot of log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!--
       Read http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/api/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html
       for more information on DaliyRollingFileAppender configuration options.
    -->
    <appender name="error" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/elg/logs/scandium-error.log"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="error"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p - [%t] [%x] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="debug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/elg/logs/scandium-debug.log"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="trace"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p [%t] - %c{1} [%x] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/elg/logs/scandium-info.log"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - [%t] [%x] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="trace" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/elg/logs/scandium-trace.log"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} - [%t] [%x] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1} - [%t] [%x] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack">
        <priority value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="trace"/>
        <appender-ref ref="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
        <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="org.quartz">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Please help to sort out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`WARN` is a more severe log level than `INFO`, and so setting your log level to `INFO` will still get warnings. The best solution is to figure out why you're getting all those warnings; they're pointing to something Quartz thinks is a real problem (you apparently have a bunch of properties set in a configuration somewhere that the target job type doesn't understand). If you absolutely can't fix the real problem, then you can set the log level to `ERROR`.

Comment: In fact we create JobDetail using JobDataMap. For that we use Map<String, Object>. So the keys of this Map is stored in separate Java class as constant. So we directly use the key name to add object to Map. Ex: public static final String systemIdK = "system-id"; is inside the ScandiumKeyBox.java (constant class) and we use it when add object to Map. Map<String, Object> jobData = new HashMap<String, Object>(); jobData.put(ScandiumKeyBox.systemIdK, "some data"); So the WARN is giving saying "No setter on Job class... for property 'system-id'". Is there any real problem on that? Hope ur reply.

Comment: Also changing INFO to ERROR didn't work. Still WARN loggers are appearing in the console.

Comment: @IndikaSampath Yes, there's a real problem; you have configuration options (set in the `Map`) that are being ignored, and the log messages are the only notice of that. Remove them from the configuration if they're not really necessary. And if you changed the log level to `ERROR` and are still getting `WARN`s, you have an override for that logger somewhere.